# How to fix the chromedriver if its not compatible with chrome version?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The Following Error is given when i run my code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
```

I have tried to download a newer version of chromdriver but it still gives me the same error. I have tried to replace the current chromedriver that's running and the one I downloaded recently but it still gave the same error, so I downloaded the compatible version of chromdriver, and then I used this line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\talha\Documents\Projects For Portfolio\SmmoBot\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

But this returns the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH
```

Comment: you could lookup a chromedriver that supports your version of chrome or just downolad Chrome in version 85

Comment: Chromedriver usually runs with an older version of Chrome. I think your best course of action is to uninstal Chrome, then reinstall the supported version.

Comment: @kwkt I wouldn't recommed this as the older version may have security flaws. I'd keep the Chrome browser updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download and use the latest [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) automatically using [webdrivermanager-python](/questions/tagged/webdrivermanager-python).

This can be achieved by installing the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) using the command:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

- Implemention through code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```

Comment: This is amazing! is there a similar solution for Java and Mavin?

Comment: @MosheSlavin Yes, there are

Comment: Yes! I have found [this repo](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) I'm working on implementing it in my projects. Thanks

Comment: @MosheSlavin Actually I had an answer with all the details and atm I'm unable to locate the discussion :/

Comment: i must add that the same problem happened again but this time i was using visual studio code and it automatically detected that selenium needed to be updated and updated it for me! i highly recomend visual studio code for intermediate programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Chrome and Chromedriver has to be the same. Best way is to keep your Chrome browser updated and just download newest version of chromedriver.

You have 2 options:

Either download the version of chromedriver fitting your actual chrome browser

or

preferred way update your chrome browser and download fitting version of chroemdriver

`My version of chrome is 87.0.4280.141`

`My version of chromedriver is 87.0.4280.88`

My chromedriver is in the same folder as my script and this is a working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: my chrome browser is up to date its my chromedriver, my chromedriver is apparently out of date but when i download a newest version it does not work and says it needs to be added to path

Comment: Well, what is your Chrome browser version?

Comment: chrome version  87.0.4280.88, check the updated question it shows the error mentioned

Comment: Good! Then here is your chromedriver version https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=87.0.4280.88/

Comment: Don't forget you are downloading a zip file, so extract and replace your actual chromedriver with new one. Then your code should be working. (or at least give a different error)

Comment: Just copy the executable chromedriver to the folder with your python file and then call `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: I cant seem to find my old chromedriver for some reason is there anyway i can get python to print out the directory path of the chromedriver?

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\talha\Documents\Projects For Portfolio\SmmoBot\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')` well what is this then? You are defining the path where is your chromedriver. Put it in your directory - where the python script is and run what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: this is the new version of chromedriver that i downloaded, i put it into the same folder as the python file and i tried to use executable_path to reference the chromdriver that i wanted to use but it didnt work and it says i need to add it to path(also i tried to do the thing you told me in your previous comment it gives the same error)

Comment: Updated the answer. You should show your code and directories as well if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the file named getDriver.py on this repo to get the correct version installed on the first run. It is working just fine untill now.
https://github.com/DevGadBadr/getSuitableChromeDriver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Options like me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url_desejada)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that with the latest version of Selenium, if you don't specify a location for the chrome driver.exe file, Selenium will automatically manage it for you. It's a feature that recently came out. For example, on my machine:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

...is all I need to access a web page. I don't have any version of chromedriver.exe installed. Selenium manages this. You just need the latest version of Selenium.

***NOTE: This post is old. The automatic management of chromedriver that Selenium has came out very recently.