# Selenium and ChromeDriverManager doesn't downloads the latest version of ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I have an error:

```
Error: Type: <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException'>
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.82 with binary path .....
```

To get latest driver I'm using this code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
```

Why on my local machine and one of the VMs, it will get the latest (version 98...) and on one of the VM, it will get only version 96.

- Is it something that need to be changed on VM to make it work correctly?

**P.S.** Two VMs are identical copies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting... Seems to be chromedriver can't detect it's browser version or does it another way than webdriver-manager. When webdriver-manager can. Need to research the priority how chromedriver detects browser version and add the same logic to python webdriver-manager library.

Answer (score 0):

The VM in which you observe:

[image: chrome=98.0]

[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is updated to the latest version. Hence, [***Webdriver Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) detects ***Chrome v98.0*** and accordingly downloads the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v98.0.4758***

---

Where as the VM in which you observe:

[image: chrome=96.0]

[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) haven't been updated since ***Chrome v96.0*** and possibly *auto-upgrade* is ***disabled***. Hence, [***Webdriver Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659636/7429447) detects ***Chrome v96.0*** and accordingly downloads the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) ***v96.0.4758***

Comment: Yes, but why does the other one detect ONLY version 96? and not 98?

Comment: Browser on the VM (where detected version 96) is version 98 this is why conflict appeared

Comment: @DSM Checkout the updated answer and let me know if any queries.

Comment: I thought about it , but as I have mentioned Chromer IS appropriately updated - `Version 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Chrome `Version 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)` is not installed at the default location. Chrome installed at the **default location** is still **v96.0**

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` - folder with this name - `98.0.4758.82`

Comment: Chrome driver 98 has some issue. Selenium worked fine for me when I used version 97 with webdriver-manager. Now it's not working and using firefox webdriver.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome version 98, download ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.80

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Download Option 2.